# How to edit python path

Tags: python, path

I use both python3.5.3 (default) and python 3.6.5 that I installed on raspberry pi. 
The path for each version is as below.
I'd like to add the path, /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, under python3.6 and remove it from python3.5. How could I do that?

```
user@raspberrypi:~ $ python3.6
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  5 2018, 18:01:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
 ['',
'/usr/local/lib/python36.zip',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']


user@raspberrypi:~ $ python3.5
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
'/usr/lib/python35.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.5',
'/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf',
'/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As each version of Python seems to maintain its own environment (and path) how's about adding this to the beginning of your program:

```
import sys

myPath='/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages' # or whatever else you want it to be

if '3.6' in sys.version and not myPath in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(myPath)
elif '3.5' in sys.version and myPath in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove(myPath)
```